# Problem while running the example program from CFITSIO Quick Start Guide

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fits

I'm trying to work with the CFITSIO library to process FITS images in C. I followed the installation guide from the documentation and I checked that it was successful installed. However when I compile the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fitsio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fitsfile *fptr;         
    char card[FLEN_CARD]; 
    int status = 0,  nkeys, ii;  /* MUST initialize status */

    fits_open_file(&fptr, argv[1], READONLY, &status);
    fits_get_hdrspace(fptr, &nkeys, NULL, &status);

    for (ii = 1; ii <= nkeys; ii++)  { 
      fits_read_record(fptr, ii, card, &status); /* read keyword */
      printf("%s\n", card);
    }
    printf("END\n\n");  /* terminate listing with END */
    fits_close_file(fptr, &status);

    if (status)          /* print any error messages */
    fits_report_error(stderr, status);
    return(status);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libcfitsio.a(zcompress.o): in function `uncompress2mem':
/home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:97: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:117: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:117: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:176: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:154: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libcfitsio.a(zcompress.o): in function `uncompress2mem_from_mem':
/home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:209: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:220: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:251: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:229: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libcfitsio.a(zcompress.o): in function `uncompress2file':
/home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:291: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:312: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:356: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:346: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libcfitsio.a(zcompress.o): in function `compress2mem_from_mem':
/home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:391: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:404: undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:435: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:413: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libcfitsio.a(zcompress.o): in function `compress2file_from_mem':
/home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:473: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:486: undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:526: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/tres-2b/Desktop/cfitsio-4.0.0/zcompress.c:514: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried passing the files as an argument on the command terminal and hard forcing a FITS file into the program, but still wasn't able to run the program successfully. I couldn't find a lot of information about this library, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not getting compilation errors, you're getting linker errors. You're missing a library that you're trying to use in your code.

Comment: @littleadv You are right, thank you. I was able to solve the problem.